# Can the standpipe for washer be relocated without moving ptrap?

Tags: plumbing, washing-machine, p-trap

In my area, the ptrap arm length (section between waste stack and ptrap) is limited to one foot per 1/4” of the pipe’s inner diameter. (at a 1/4” per foot slope)

I want to move my washer a bit further away from the waste stack than that (8feet overall), and i can’t enlarge the pipes (because the waste stack is common property in my building — what i own is the 2" threaded insert into it, and everything “upstream” from that).

Could i leave my current ptrap in place and extend the standpipe side of the setup instead? Or do a combination of both— i.e move the ptrap, and then “nudge” the standpipe further?

[image: example drain setup]

Comment: How far do you intend to move the washer from the standpipe?  That dimension  will give us a better idea of what you are trying to accomplish.  Maybe just a longer hose?

Comment: about 8 feet away.

Comment: leaving the drain in place, and extending the washer drain hose would be going beyond manufacturer recommendations (1.5m max). would the flexible extension have to run waist-high along the wall on a slope to avoid trapping water?